# VB CommonDialog.MaxFileSize

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, upgrade, vb6-migration

If VB6 you can use (sometimes have to use):

```
commonDialog1.MaxFileSize = "32767"
```

This is not acceptable in .NET, is there a way to do this in .NET? Or do I need to worry with this at all? If not please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (sometimes have to use)

No, the last version of Visual Basic where that property still made sense was VB4.  The last 16-bit version of VB.  The kind of version where you'd still worry a bit how much storage is required to store the filenames of all the selected files when you allow the user to select multiple files.

There is no conceivable way that can be a problem on a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: I found the assertion curious so I just tested to make sure and definitely a VB6 application will crash if `MaxFileSize` is too small for the returned file list.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to worry about this in .NET.  `MaxFileSize` was used in VB6 to allocate extra memory for storing lists of filenames and paths when multiple selections were enabled.  This is managed dynamically by the framework in .NET when using `OpenFileDialog` and the like.

Answer (score 1):

It definately mattered in VB 5 & 6 when you wanted to allow multiselection.

> An integer specifying the maximum size of the filename in bytes. The
>   range for this property is 1 - 32K. The default is 256.